# Input[type=text] transition delay not working

Tags: css

I'm using the following styles for a simple input text box, and I want the dashed border to animate to solid on focus and vice versa.

```
        input {
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: large;
            border: 2px solid #1bd55a;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        input[type=text] {
            width: 500px;
            height: 30px;
            color: #616161;
            padding-left: 6px;
            border-style: dashed;
            background-color: rgba(27, 213, 90, 0.12);
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
        input[type=text]:focus {
            border-style: solid;
            outline: none; /* gets rid of the blue outline. */
        }
```

However with the current code, the transition between dash and solid is immediate, no animation there. I'm animating the single property, and I know it's possible to make this work with svg's `stroke` property, so how can I apply this properly to text input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately border-style is not an animatable property. However, you could achieve the effect with some extra markup and border-color.

```css
   input {
          font-family: inherit;
          font-size: large;
          border: 2px solid #1bd55a;
          border-radius: 5px;
      }
      input[type=text] {
          width: 500px;
          height: 30px;
          color: #616161;
          padding-left: 6px;
          background-color: rgba(27, 213, 90, 0.12);
          border-color: rgba(27, 213, 90, 0.12);
          transition: 0.3s;
          margin: -2px;
      }
      input[type=text]:focus {
          border-color: #1bd55a;
          outline: none; /* gets rid of the blue outline. */
      }

      div.extra-border {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 2px dashed #1bd55a;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="extra-border">
      <input type="text" placeholder="text here" />
    </div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thtyxL7d/). Not precisely the same transition as what `svg`s give you, but not bad.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp

border-style property is not animatable.